# How to make a nice button using Jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, file, mobile, external, transition

I want to make a button using jquery mobile to redirect the user to an other page with a slide animation for example and with rel="external" in order to load external js file .

```
<a data-theme="e" href="page.html" rel="external" data-role="button" data-transition="flip">
```

but there is no transition ! If i use

```
<a data-theme="e" href="page.html" data-role="button" data-transition="flip">
```

there is the flip transition but the external file isn't loaded !

What should i use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

data-rel="external" means you are not using ajax, so there wont be any transition because it will take you to a new page. What you can do is to load the external url with custom jquery ajax function for your button, use the flip-animation and load the external js on ajax-success.